# Truecrypt password prompt

Tags: windows-7, windows, encryption, truecrypt

Am trying to get it so that when I click on an encrypted file, a truecrypt password prompt appears and then upon entering correct password, windows explorer opens the newly mounted volume so that I can browse the contents.

If I open a cmd prompt and enter this:

```
ftype TrueCryptVolume="c:\program files\truecrypt\truecrypt.exe" /a /cn /q /v "a.tc" 
assoc .tc=TrueCryptVolume
```

then i just need to rename the truecrypt volume as a.tc. A prompt does appear and the volume is decrypted, however I can't get windows explorer to automatically open the newly mounted volume. Truecrypt itself has such an option, to open windows explorer for newly mounted volumes, however it won't work with the above method.

Any idea how to make it work? Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs at http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=command-line-usage, you can use the `/e` switch to cause Explorer to open the mounted volume.